# Excel Formula for CountIFs with multiple cell referenced Named Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count all the instances within a table (table name = "data") using the CountIFs formula:

=COUNTIFS(data[[Status]:[Status]],"="&INDEX(Actionable,1), data[[Age (Days)]:[Age (Days)]],">"&"14", data[[Support Owner]:[Support Owner]],"="&$B38)

The formula works right now because I am only referencing the value in the first row of the Named Range "Actionable" by using the INDEX function.

What I want to do is be able to have the formula look at all the values in the named range and find all the instances in the column data[[Status]:[Status]].

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the named range alone as the criterion then the `COUNTIFS` formula will return an array (one value for each value in `Actionable`) so you can then wrap the whole thing in a `SUMPRODUCT` function to get the sum of that array without "array entry". That sum represents your total count, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(data[[Status]:[Status]],Actionable,data[[Age (Days)]:[Age (Days)]],">14", data[[Support Owner]:[Support Owner]],$B38))`

Note - if Actionable contains duplicates then you will also count those values more than once

Comment: You are awesome!!!!! you have just helped me crunch a 30K character formula down sooooo much!!!!

Comment: Any ideas on an option for adding another Named Range that has multiple cell references? WS_CaseOwners is the second Named Range.

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(CaseReport[[Product]:[Product]],"="&"", CaseReport[[Status]:[Status]],Actionable,CaseReport[[Age (Hours)]:[Age (Hours)]],">"&$N$45, CaseReport[[Support Tier]:[Support Tier]],"="&N$46, CaseReport[[Case Owner]:[Case Owner]],WS_CaseOwners))